# previously inserted value gets inserted automatically on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

What could be the query or what could be the solution of inserting values in database through html form via PHP but everytime I refresh the page the previously inserted value gets inserted again?

```
if (isset($_POST["insert1"])) { 
    $inrtno = $_POST["inrouteno"];
    $instp = $_POST["instop"];

    if ($inrtno !=''||$instp !='') {
        $query = mysqli_query($datacon,"REPLACE INTO `stops`(`sn`, `routeno`, `stop`) VALUES ('NULL','$inrtno','$instp')");
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Insertion Successful !!!')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";   
    }
}
```

Comment: Most web browsers usually fire off a warning when doing a re-POST might cause inconsistencies.  If your data model doesn't tolerate duplicates, then you should put constraints in place on the MySQL side.

Comment: Indeed, even deleting it the browser will just send it again anyway. Well, redirecting the person to the same page after the post is inserted should fix it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated previously (and for my own understanding), every time you refresh the page, the request is sent again. Mind me for forgetting that, thank you @ADyson.

So, a solution for that would be redirecting the user to the same form after the insertion is made.

Assuming this file would be test.php, for example:

```
if (isset($_POST["insert1"])) { 
    $inrtno = $_POST["inrouteno"];
    $instp = $_POST["instop"];

    if ($inrtno !=''||$instp !='') {
        $query = mysqli_query($datacon,"REPLACE INTO `stops`(`sn`, `routeno`, `stop`) VALUES ('NULL','$inrtno','$instp')");
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Insertion Successful !!!')</script>";

        sleep('3');
        header('Location: /test.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you refresh the page you are resubmitting the POST variables, so the PHP still runs. Additionally, your query is in danger of [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page the browser asks you to re-submit the request, so the value gets transferred again. So put a condition when you insert data that will check if the record already exists or not.